# How to create bitbucket repository using curl?

Tags: curl, bitbucket, bitbucket-server, bitbucket-api

I have tried multiple ways like

```
curl -you 'USERNAME' https://api.bitbucket.org/1.0/repositories -d '{"name":"REPO"}'
curl -k -X POST --user user: pass \ "https://api.bitbucket.org/1.0/repositories" -d "name=project_name"
```

What am I missing?

Comment: What is the error that you're getting?

The following works for me:

"curl --user USER https://api.bitbucket.org/1.0/repositories/ --data name=REPO"

Answer (score 6):

Nevermind the following worked for Bitbucket version 4.4

```
curl -X POST -v -u $uservar:$passvar http://<redacted>/rest/api/1.0/projects/$projectkeyvar/repos -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d "{\"name\": \"$reponamevar\",\"scmId\": \"git\", \"forkable\": true }"
```

I was using this in a shell script, hence the variables.